# Error general en Visual Studio 2017 (proyecto xamarin)

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2017

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hola, tengo un problema, tengo un una solucion con dos proyectos, uno web y un proyecto compartido Xamarin.
Lo que sucede es que es como si se hubiera "roto" el proyecto xamarin, como se ve en la imagen está todo subrayado en rojo, en todos dice, "Falta una directiva using o referencia a un ensablado".
El proyecto web que esta en la misma solución funciona bien.
Abro otro proyecto que tenia de prueba de xamarin proyecto compartido y sucede lo mismo. 
Otra cosa rara que sucede es que lo ejecuto lo corre bien, y si lo compilo no da errores.
Gracias
pd: ya reinicie el visual, la pc, etc

Comment: Has probado _Limpiar_ seguido de _Recompilar_?

Comment: sisi, muchas veces

Comment: Estos problemas son complicados. Te digo un par de cosas que se me ocurren: borra las carpetas `bin` y `obj` de tu proyecto. Borra tambien el archivo del intellisense (debe llamarse `Proyecto.sdf`). Intenta arrancar el vs en modo seguro por si hay algun plugin molestando (`devenv /Safemode`). Por último, asegurate de tener la ultima versión de Xamarin (me suena que había algun bug de ese tipo en versiones anteriores)

Comment: Hola, gracias a todos, creo que lo solucione actualizando XAMARIN desde el NuGet, o mejor dicho, desinstalando y instalando la ultima versión.